# How to write the function definition for this prototyoe

Tags: c++, class, prototype, definition

I wrote the prototype for a client function called "mergeLists", which merges two sorted lists into a third sorted list:

```
template <class Item Type>
void mergeList (const SortedList < ItemType> & list1,
                       const SortedList < ItemType > & list2,
                       SortedList < ItemType > & result);
```

It uses the sorted SortedList class:

```
#ifndef SORTEDLIST_H
#define SORTEDLIST_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>   // Needed for the exit function
using namespace std;

const int MAX_LENGTH = 100; // Maximum number of components

template <class ItemType> // You may also choose to use
                          // typedef statement
class SortedList
{
public:
    // Constructor
    SortedList();
    // Post: Empty list has been created. length has been set to zero.

    // Knowledge responsibilities
    int getLength() const;
    // Post: Returns the length of the list
    bool isEmpty() const;
    // Post: Returns true if list is empty; false otherwise
    bool isFull() const;
    // Post: Returns true if list is full; false otherwise
    bool isInList(const ItemType& item) const;
    // Post: Returns true if item is int the list; false otherwise
    int binarySearch(const ItemType& item) const;
    // Function to search the list for a given item using binary 
    // search algorithm.
    // Post: If item is found, returns the index in the array where
    // item is found; otherwise, return -1.

    // Action Responsibilities
    void resetList();
    // Post: The list becomes empty. length has been set to zero.
    void insert(const ItemType& item);
    // Function to insert item to the list. However, first 
    // the list is searched to see whether the item to be inserted is
    // already in the list.
    // Pre: The list items are sorted in ascending order.
    // Post: item is in the list and list items are sorted in ascending
    // order. If item is added, length++; if the list is already full or
    // item is already in the list, an appropriate message is displayed.
    void remove(const ItemType& item);
    // Function to remove item from the list. 
    // Pre: The list items are sorted in ascending order.
    // Post: If item is found in the list, it is removed from the list
    // and length is decremented by one. The list items remain sorted in
    // ascending order.

    // Overloaded [] operator declaration.  
        // This function returns a reference to the element in the 
    // array indexed by index.               
    ItemType& operator[](const int& index);

private:
    ItemType list[MAX_LENGTH]; // array to hold the list elements
    int length;                // to store the length of the list
};


//**********************************************************
template <class ItemType>
SortedList<ItemType>::SortedList()
{
    length = 0;
}

//**********************************************************
template <class ItemType>
int SortedList<ItemType>::getLength() const
{
    return length;
}

//**********************************************************
template <class ItemType>
bool SortedList<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return (length == 0);
}

//**********************************************************
template <class ItemType>
bool SortedList<ItemType>::isFull() const
{
    return (length == MAX_LENGTH);
}

//**********************************************************
template <class ItemType>
bool SortedList<ItemType>::isInList(const ItemType& item) const
{
    int loc;
    loc = binarySearch(item);
    if (loc != -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//**********************************************************
template <class ItemType>
int SortedList<ItemType>::binarySearch(const ItemType& item) const
{
    int first = 0;      // lower bound on list
    int last = length - 1;  // upper bound on list
    int middle;             // middle index
    bool found = false;

    while (last >= first && !found )
    {
        middle = (first + last ) / 2;
        if (item < list[middle])
            // item is not in list[middle..last]
            last = middle - 1;
        else if (item > list[middle])
            // item is not in list[first..middle]
            first = middle + 1;
        else
            // item == list[middle]
            found = true;
    }
    if (found)
        return middle;
    else 
        return -1;
}   

//**********************************************************
template <class ItemType>
void SortedList<ItemType>::resetList()
{
    length = 0;
}

//**********************************************************
template <class ItemType>
void SortedList<ItemType>::insert(const ItemType& item)
{
    int loc = length - 1; // the index for the inserted item
    if (length == MAX_LENGTH)  // check if the list is full
        cout << "Cannot insert in a full list." << endl;
    else if (binarySearch(item) != -1) // check if item is in list
        cout << "The item is already in the list. "
              << "No duplicates are allowed." << endl;
    else
    {
        // Search for insertion point beginning at the end. Items
        // are compared and shifted until insertion place is found.
        while (loc >= 0 && item < list[loc])
        {
            list[loc + 1] = list[loc];
            loc--;      
        }
        list[loc + 1] = item; // insert item
        length++;
    }
}

//*********************************************************
template <class ItemType>
void SortedList<ItemType>::remove(const ItemType& item)
{
    int loc;
    loc = binarySearch(item);
    if (loc == -1) // check if item is in list
        cout << "The item is not in the list. "
             << "Cannot delete a non-existing item." << endl;
    else
    {
        // Shift list[(loc+1)..length-1] up one position
        for (int index = loc + 1; index < length; index++)
            list[index - 1] = list[index];
        length--;           
    }
}

//**********************************************************
template <class ItemType>
ItemType& SortedList<ItemType>::operator[](const int& index)
{
   if (index < 0 || index >= length)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Index out of range.\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   return list[index];
}

#endif
```

The preconditions of the function are: list1 and list2 have been initialized and are sorted; list1 and list2 do not have any items in common. The postconditions are: the result is a sorted list that contains all of the items from list1 and list2. 
I want to write the function definition for mergeLists using this SortedList class, but I am not sure how to do it.

I think it would start somethin like this:

```
SortedList <ItemType> & mergeList ( )
```

Answer (score 2):

The declaration should be this:

```
template <class ItemType>
void mergeList (const SortedList < ItemType> & list1,
                       const SortedList < ItemType > & list2,
                       SortedList < ItemType > & result);
```

Then inside the list, you need to do:

- Pick an element at index `i1` from `list1`.
- Pick an element at index `i2` from `list2`.

Insert the lower of the two into `result`, and increment the corresponding `i1` or `i2`.

When you reach the end of either list, insert remaining items of the other list. You may have to care about duplicates (if dups aren't allowed, in that if value from `list1` is the same as in `list2`, then you mustn't insert both).